# Format exception is given

Tags: c#

Input string was not in a correct format.

```
public List<int> GetNodeIDInfo()
{
    nodeData_List = this.GetNodeInfo();

    for(int iNode = 0; iNode<nodeData_List.Count; iNode++)
    {
        string[] str = nodeData_List.ElementAt(0);
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            nodeID_List.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
        }
    }
    return nodeID_List;
}
```

what is wrong in this?

Comment: What have you tried doing? StackOverflow isn't really a "gimme code" website - you get much more positive and useful feedback if you give an attempt at doing it yourself and post what you have tried and where you got stuck. Additionally cutting down the amount of code you post to what is absolutely needed to help you with the problem - e.g. we don't really care about the implementation of these methods as the question stands - you could just have the signatures.

Comment: What is a member? Please either give some context or leave out references to undefined terms.

Comment: public double Getlengthofmember(int _memberId)
        {
            double x1 ,x2;
            double y1, y2;
            double z1, z2;

            var node_dict = _nodeDetails.GetNodeID_AlongWithCoordinates();
            var mem_dict = this.GetMemberID_AlongWithStartandEndNode();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<int, int>> item in mem_dict)
            {
                
            }

            return 1.0;//to be changed after calculation
        }

Comment: stuck in the middle please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following:

```
//this variable is for saving results
Dictionary<int,double> memberLengthMap = new Dictionary<int,double>();

Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double, double>> nodes = GetNodeID_AlongWithCoordinates();
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int,int>> members = GetMemberID_AlongWithStartandEndNode();
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Tuple<int,int>> member in members)
{
    Tuple<double, double, double> startNode = nodes[member.Value.Item1];
    Tuple<double, double, double> endNode = nodes[member.Value.Item2];
    double xDiff = (startNode.Item1 - endNode.Item1);
    double yDiff = (startNode.Item2 - endNode.Item2);
    double zDiff = (startNode.Item3 - endNode.Item3);

    double distance = Math.Sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff + zDiff*zDiff);
    memberLengthMap.Add(member.Key,distance);
}
```

I hope that helped

Comment: thanks alot, but still getting an error of following :  'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,double>' does not contain a definition for 'put' and no extension method 'put' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,double>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  I have using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; all of these included

Comment: the solution is updated. notice that in this code, length is calculated for all the members.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(TO) is giving me "Format exception was unhandled by given code

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(TO) is giving me "Format exception was unhandled by given code please help

Comment: If it is another question, open a different thread and place your code over there so that I can understand what exactly your question is.